# add uiview before slide menu controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have successfully added slide menu in my application with the help of [JWSlideMenu](https://github.com/jeremieweldin/JWSlideMenu)

but before showing or adding slide menu there is requirement of a view which must add to first controller. On this view there shouldn't be slidemenu view.

For it I have added uiview to first controller but it also showing navigation bar.

```
UIView *test=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -44, 320, 460)];
test.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:test];
```

How to hide slidemenu view or navigation bar. Or can we add slide menu view in first controller instead of app delegate.[image]

Comment: Try this .. 

paste this code in your HomeViewController's ViewDidLoad method

    `TestController *tC = [[TestController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tC];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:nController animated:NO];`

Comment: @Bala It is not presenting testcontroller.

Comment: @Bala Thanks for your response. I have added the modal view in app delegate under slide menu instead of first controller which solves my issue.                                                     present *tC = [[present alloc] initWithNibName:@"present" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UINavigationController *nController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tC];
    [JWSlideMenuViewController presentModalViewController:nController animated:YES];